# Import attributes using CSV with woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, csv, import, woocommerce, attributes

I am importing bulk products via Woocommerce using a .csv file.

Everything works as it should apart from the attribute I am trying to upload.

I am uploading the brand name as an attribute. I currently have the following on my .csv:

Header = attribute:brand

Value = "*brand name*"

I am not sure if this correct, but even if it is, I'm unsure which fields to map them to?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not Sure how you are importing via Woocommerce its self?

1.maybe you need a specific keyword rather the "attribute:brand" ( or you can define a different reference)

2.check that all the ranges in the csv are readable by woo-commerce

**otherwise try looking for a plugin called 'all Import' works fantastic**

Comment: Thanks for you all Import suggestion. You're right - it's amazing.

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming you are using WooCommerce import that comes with the default install.

All the documentation is old on this so some of the column headers are bad. At least from my experience. I exported a variable product I made to get the correct column headers.

For attributes you need these columns:

Attribute 1 name | Attribute 1 value(s) | Attribute 1 visible | Attribute 1 global

size | Small, Medium | 0 or 1 | 0 or 1|

You also need to import the parent items first with the column header "type" and the value as "variable"

The next import is the variations which have a "type" of variation

these are two .csv files that I used. if you copy the row headers I believe they have all the values currently used by the importer
http://www.midnighthtml.com/uploads/Final_Swim_225.csv

http://www.midnighthtml.com/uploads/Final_Swim_Child_225.csv

Comment: Links are dead.